# Successive build/releases to azure web app through DevOps pushes new build one directory deeper

Tags: reactjs, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy a ReactJS app to my Azure Web App through Azure DevOps. I've created a project on DevOps for it, and I'm attempting to set up a continuous integration pipeline so that every commit to master triggers a new build and deploys it to the web app. The azure-pipelines.yml file that specifies the build instructions is as below:

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

trigger:
- master

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

I created this file using the instructions provided at [Build, test, and deploy Javascript Apps in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript?view=vsts&tabs=yaml)

The build succeeds just fine, and I then created a release for the build using the following settings:
[Azure release pipeline task setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y2RN.png)

(Deploy Azure App Service > App Type: Web App > Package/Folder:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip)

I've also configured the physical path for the web app on azure to be site\wwwroot\build

The first time I create the build and release it, it gets deployed fine, and I see the changes reflected on the web app. **However**, every subsequent build does not automatically get updated to show on the web app. Using the diagnostic console on Kudu, I see that new builds are going one directory deeper, eg the next build will have the physical path of site\wwwroot\build\build. To see the new build, I have to manually change the path for the web app each time.

Edit: Here are some snapshots of the Azure Web App settings, and of the console on Kudu.
[image: Issue shown on Kudu diagnostic console]
[image: Azure Web App Settings (1)]
[image: Azure Web App Settings (2)]
[image: Azure Web App Settings (With physical path)(3)]

**My question is this**: How can I set up this entire process so that new builds REPLACE old builds on web app, and avoid them instead being nested inside the old build?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my side, would you mind sharing reproduced demo code? If there is a snapshot for Azure Web Appsetting will be more helpful.

Comment: Hi @tom , I've added some snapshots. Please let me know if you need anything else, and thank you for your help

Comment: It is very odd.  It seems that there is no difference from my settings. If you set physical path to be `site\wwwroot\`, what will happen? If possible, could you please share your reproduced `demo code` on github or other git repro?

Comment: @tom , changing the path to site\wwwroot and visiting the website displays the error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." I'll add a link to another react project that I did earlier (with TypeScript) where I faced the same error during DevOps deployment:
https://github.com/sannan06/MSA-recipe-frontend
Just as a reminder, the first deploy works successfully, the issue crops up when I deploy subsequent builds (which are getting pushed a level deeper). Please let me know if you need anything else.